# Matching XML tags containing invalid characters with regular expressions

Tags: java, xml, regex

I have a java program that takes a xml as a input and check with the list of allowable characters inside the tag using regex and should return a entire tag that contains other than the allowable charactes like this special characters

XMl Input

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PayLoad>
<requestRows>****</requestRows>
<requestRowLength>1272</requestRowLength>
<exceptionTimestamp>2012070202281068-0700</exceptionTimestamp>
<exceptionTimestamp>201$2070202281068-0700</exceptionTimestamp>
<exceptionTimestamp>20120(702022810680700</exceptionTimestamp>
<exceptionDetail>NO DATA AVAILABLE FOR TIME PERIOD SPECIFIED   =</exceptionDetail>
</PayLoad>
```

Allowable character list

```
\! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = > ? @ A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z [ \ ] ^ _ ` a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z { | } ~
```

I have tried like below

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        List<String> specialCharList = new ArrayList<String>();
        try{
                String responseXml="test";
                String SPECIAL_CHARACTER ="(<[\\w\\d]*>(?=[^<]*[^<\\w\\!\\#\\$\\%\\&\\\'\\(\\)\\\\ \\*\\\"\\+\\,\\-\\~\\}\\{\\.\\/\\:\\;\\=\\?\\@\\]\\[\\\\\\`\\|]).*</[\\w\\d]*>)";
                if (!(responseXml == null || responseXml.toString().length() < 1 || responseXml.toString().equals("")))
                {
                    Pattern patternObject = Pattern.compile(SPECIAL_CHARACTER);   
                    Matcher patternMatcher = patternObject.matcher(responseXml);   
                    while(patternMatcher.find())
                    {   
                      specialCharList.add(patternMatcher.group());
                    }
                    if(specialCharList.isEmpty() || specialCharList.size()<0)
                    {
                        specialCharList.add("No Special Character's Detected");
                    }
                }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
        System.out.println(specialCharList);
    }
```

But its not working as expected.
How to write a Regex for the above scenario? Pls help me

Comment: Pls find the java code which i tried

Comment: What did you expect, and how does the outcome differ from that expectation?

Comment: `catch(Exception e) {  }` is going to make it hard for you to work out what's happening

Answer (score 0):

First let's address a couple of mistakes on your regex

```
(<[\w\d]*>(?=[^<]*[^<\w\!\#\$\%\&\'\(\)\ \*\"\+\,\-\~\}\{\.\/\:\;\=\?\@\]\[\\\`\|]).*</[\w\d]*>)
```

The `\w` is the shorthand to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`; including both `\w` and `\d` inside the same character set `[...]` is redundant, so `<[\w\d]*>` can simplified to `<[\w]*>`.

Also, you don't need to do any escaping inside character sets, except for backslashes '\', closing brackets ']' and sometimes the minus sign '-'. For whitespace characters, you should use `\s` - it includes single spaces, tabbed spaces and linebreaks. Thus, simplifying:

```
[^<\w\!\#\$\%\&\'\(\)\ \*\"\+\,\-\~\}\{\.\/\:\;\=\?\@\]\[\\\`\|]
```

becomes

```
[^<\w!#$%&'()\s*"+,-~}{./:;=?@\][\\`|]
```

The following regex is not very efficient: character exclusion always increase computation a lot. It will match tags containing one or more "invalid" characters.

```
<[\w]*>((?!<[\w]*>).)*[^<\w!#$%&'()\s*"+,-~}{./:;=?@\][\\`|]((?!<[\w]*>).)*</[\w]*>
```

It's worth noting that if performance matters, you should really rethink your error parsing method.

This website offers an excellent introduction to regular expressions

http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html